# How to remove ubuntu from my windows 7?

Tags: uninstall

I have a windows 7 pc but ubuntu does not allow me to go to a normal windows screen so i want to remove ubuntu from my pc.

Answer (score 0):

What happened to your dual-boot? I suggest to install grub2.

in terminal:
 `sudo apt-get install grub2`

this will allow you at the beginning to choose witch OS you want to boot. For gaming win and for working use Ubuntu... Hope this helps.